# Adding a locale on Monterey

Tags: macos, monterey

I have a Postgres database with locale `nb_NO.UTF-8` (Norwegian bokmål). When trying to move this to another Mac with Monterey (`pg_dumpall` + `psql file.sql`) , I got the error that that locale doesn't exist. Looking further, `locale -a` tells me that it does indeed not exist, just `no_NO.UTF-8`. I can't find out how to add it. It looks like Apple put the locales on the operating system disk, and this one has been made read only.

I have tried `sudo localedef -f UTF-8 -i no_NO.UTF-8 nb_NO.UTF-8`. This fails because of write permissions. I have tried the same after disabling SIP, this also fails for the same reason. I have tried copying the locale folder in `/usr/share/locale` (with and without SIP enabled), but that also fails for the same reason.

How can I add new locales?